# How can we set sizes for Product image while uploading in Admin Section

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, product-images, image-upload

I am using Magento 1.9 version.

I am working on creating products in Magento, due to some specific conditions I need the size of images of uploaded image in defined ratio.

So I need to set the width and Height of a image when we are uploading it in Image section of a Manage Product.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the base product image dimensions in config -> catalog -> product image.

[image]

I expect it would be possible to write a custom module to further perform image resizing but it would be simpler to either create your images in the format you want or use a free image editing package (such as IrfanView) to bulk modify the images you want to use before you upload them.